# Handle batch size in custom data augmentation layer - tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, layer, batchsize

I have implemented this simple data augmentation layer, basically it rotates images by a specific angle (I know it can be done via ImageDataGenerator, but it is just to explain the problem).

```py
    class RandomRotation(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

        def __init__(self, rotation_range=None, **kwargs):
            super(RandomRotation, self).__init__(**kwargs)    
 

        def call(self, images, training=None, **kwargs):

            batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]

            if training is None:
               training = K.learning_phase()

            if not training:
               return images

            angles = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, batch_size)
            images = tfa.image.rotate(images, angles)
```

My model, which includes this layer, is then trained via fit method using ImageDataGenerator to automatically get a generator. I get this error because the value of batch size is None.

> TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

as first row of the script solved the problem.